# iOS 13: Resize UITabBar Height Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios13

Has anyone else noticed that changing the tab bar height programmatically is not working in iOS 13? Does anyone have a workaround? Same code works perfectly in iOS 11 and 12, but the tab bar is not resizing in iOS 13. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Without a snippet of your code it's hard to say what's wrong, but setting tab bar height's by subclassing UITabBarController and setting the tab bar height in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` works in both iOS 12 and 13.

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 120
        var tabFrame = tabBar.frame
        tabFrame.size.height = tabBarHeight
        tabFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - tabBarHeight
        tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @evanjd

Comment: Ah ok, the difference for me is using viewDidLayoutSubviews() instead of viewWillLayoutSubviews(). Thanks!

Comment: This is not working in ios 13